# Getting H2O working on Nimbix cloud servers

Tags: h2o

I am trying to build a new application on Nimbix so I can use the latest H2O releases (the H2O community versions on the Nimbix servers are outdated).

I have tried building a new application using the instructions provided here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cloud-integration/nimbix.html

And using the Docker Repository: opsh2oai/h2oai_nae
and the Git Source URL: http://github.com/h2oai/h2o3-nae

System architecture is set to Intel x86.

I pull the application and logout and log back in.

I can start a Jupyter notebook. However, I cannot import H2O (No module named 'h2o')

Also, it is not clear what the differences between H2o3, H2o3 for POWER8, and H2oAI?

In addition, which version has the GPU-enabled algos (H2O with GPU-Enabled Machine Learning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- That's the wrong image, the right one is: opsh2oai/h2o3_nae and the
  GitHub you have is correct.
- H2o3 is [h2o-3](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/), and "H2o3 for POWER8" is for IBM; the H2OAI is not meant to be public and has been removed.
- We have not enabled GPU on the Nimbix cloud to-date.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I was able to use the GPU-enabled version about two weeks, so I am assuming it was removed? Also, any estimate when the GPU enabled version will be available on Nimbix?

Comment: H2O.ai and Nimbix Bring Next-Gen GPU-Powered AI to Cloud: https://www.h2o.ai/h2o-ai-and-nimbix-bring-next-gen-gpu-powered-ai-to-cloud/

Comment: You can use the Deep Water version for now which has GPU support. We will release a new GPU-enabled version right after next stable release of h2o-3 (~July 22, 2017).